# Sending params with hyperlink

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grails, hyperlink

I'm working on a grails project and I'm editing my **views** so that I can use **BootStrap**

Here I want to replace a **g:link** with a  **hyperlink** and I have to send some **params(id)** to the controller

This is my code:

```
<g:link controller="sponsorship" action="create" params="['tekEvent.id': tekEventInstance?.id]">MyLink</g:link>
```

I tried using :

```
<a href="${createLink(controller: 'sponsorship' , action: 'create')}/${tekEventInstance?.id}">MyLink</a>
```

and it works,but I don't think using "/" always works like this one and I'm interested in using somthing like:

```
<a href="${createLink(controller: 'sponsorship' , action: 'create',params:['tekEvent.id': tekEventInstance?.id])}
```

but I get bad errors!

Can any one help me on this?

Comment: The g:link creates an hyperlink, so you can use Bootsrap without any trouble. I wonder why you want to recreate the grails hyperlink generator, if it's not to create bugs on your app. Morehover, you said you "get bad errors", but which ones ?

Comment: As you mentioned I used g:link and it's okay with bootstrap.But I have another problem :
I have wrapped a <button> tag inside <g:link> so that the link looks like a button,but when I click on it it redirects me to wrong GSP page but when I open it in new tab it works correctly!!!
Do you have any idea whats going wrong? @Joch
Using bootstrap class: btn will solve this one.

<g:link class:"btn btn-info">....</g:link>

Comment: thanks for your help @Joch

Comment: I was also going to add an answer but Mikelis has answerd and to append to that what would be so wrong with ? <button href="${createLink(controller: 'sponsorship', action: 'create'])}?tekEvent.id=${tekEventInstance?.id}"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all -  **Don't wrap button around `<a>` tag**. If you want a button to be a link, use `href` inside it:

```
<button href="${createLink(...)}"/>
```

Second - If you have only one param and you want it to behind a slash, don't give it as map of params, but just an id:

```
<button href="${createLink(controller: 'sponsorship', action: 'create', id: tekEventInstance?.id])}"/>
```

Hope this helps! :)